Error importing numpy you should not try to import numpy from its source directory;
When I try to import numpy and matplotlib I get an error:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
File /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/numpy/core/__init__.py:24
     23 try:
---> 24     from . import multiarray
     25 except ImportError as exc:

File /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/numpy/core/multiarray.py:10
      9 import functools
---> 10 from . import overrides
     11 from . import _multiarray_umath

File /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/numpy/core/overrides.py:8
      7 from .._utils._inspect import getargspec
----> 8 from numpy.core._multiarray_umath import (
      9     add_docstring,  _get_implementing_args, _ArrayFunctionDispatcher)
     12 ARRAY_FUNCTIONS = set()

ImportError: dlopen(/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/numpy/core/_multiarray_umath.cpython-312-darwin.so, 0x0002): tried: '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/numpy/core/_multiarray_umath.cpython-312-darwin.so' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'arm64', need 'x86_64')), '/System/Volumes/Preboot/Cryptexes/OS/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/numpy/core/_multiarray_umath.cpython-312-darwin.so' (no such file), '/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/numpy/core/_multiarray_umath.cpython-312-darwin.so' (mach-o file, but is an incompatible architecture (have 'arm64', need 'x86_64'))

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
File /Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/site-packages/numpy/__init__.py:130
    129 try:
...
    141 # mapping of {name: (value, deprecation_msg)}

ImportError: Error importing numpy: you should not try to import numpy from
        its source directory; please exit the numpy source tree, and relaunch
        your python interpreter from there.

I do not know how to resolve it.
I tried uninstalling and installing and I don't think I am importing numpy from it's source directory. I have numpy and matplotlib installed.

What is the content of the directory from which you import numpy? Have you tried to run python from another directory, and import numpy there?
